# Reading local event log?

Tags: c#, winforms, readeventlog

Here i am trying to read the local system event log using c# using this code-

```
 string eventLogText = "";
        try
        {
            var eventLog = new EventLog("logname", "machinename");
            foreach (var entry in eventLog.Entries)
            {
                 eventLogText += entry;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception eg)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(eg.Message);
        }
```

It is working well, but the problem is, in the variable **eventLogText** i get only **System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntry** repeatedly, may be this is very common mistake but i don't know what to do as i am very new to the c# as well as programming too.

Secondly i want to know that if a system is not logged in using **Administrator** account, in that case reading event log will cause any exception or error and if it will what will be the solution for it ?

Need help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: for the 2nd question - you can try :)

Comment: what would you like to do with the read data?

Comment: Oh yes, why this idea didn't come to my mind :)

Comment: i want to filter the data on some condition then , like most recent event entry.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your first question, you are just adding the variable `entry` to the string, which is calling the `ToString` method on that variable. The default implementation of ToString is to return the name of the class. (Hence the repeated `System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntry`output)

You will need to use [the members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlogentry.aspx) in the `EventLogEntry` class to retrieve the data you are interested in. For example, this console application will print the source and message of the first 10 entries in the Application event log:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    StringBuilder eventLogText = new StringBuilder();
    try
    {
        var eventLog = new EventLog("Application");
        var tenMostRecentEvents = eventLog.Entries
                                            .Cast<EventLogEntry>()
                                            .Reverse()
                                            .Take(10);
        foreach (EventLogEntry entry in tenMostRecentEvents)
        {
            eventLogText.AppendLine(String.Format("{0} - {1}: {2}", 
                                          entry.Source, 
                                          entry.TimeWritten, 
                                          entry.Message));
        }

        Console.WriteLine(eventLogText.ToString());
    }
    catch (System.Security.SecurityException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
    Console.ReadLine(); 
}
```

Regarding your second question, your code will need the appropriate permissions to read that event log. For example, if I change the code read the Security event log using this line `var eventLog = new EventLog("Security");` I will receive a security exception. You can check [this answer for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13494867/how-to-read-event-log-without-administrative-permissions-in-net)

Hope it helps!